# How should I use history.js

Tags: javascript, html, url-rewriting, history.js

I am a beginner to JS. and I am learning how to use HTML history API to chnage the URL.
Act , I want to append query string parameters to the URL after Ajax call is made.
Which files do I need to include in my code, is it just history.js?   I dont know how to use this API(not asking about the coding part of that).

an dafter wiriting the pushstate method, do I need to give popstate also?
Basically , if I have used Pushstate to append query String parameters to URL, DO I always nee dto give popstate()?
Thanks iin advance

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this, it explains everything you need 
http://html5doctor.com/history-api/